# regex for search and replace

Tags: regex

I'm doing a search and replace and need to replace all characters that are **not** a comma `","`.

How do I search for all characters in any order?

For example:

```
string, like , this
```

... Will become:

```
replace,replace,replace,
```

Answer (score 4):

Matching any non-comma chars: [^,]+

so in perl: s/[^,]+/replace/g

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you can do this:

```
my $string = "string, like , this";
my $replacement = "replace";
print $string, "\n";
$string =~ s/[^,]+/$replacement/g;
print $string, "\n";
```

Comment: assume you meant $replacement

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the matching text in parenthesis and then replace that for instance search for:

```
([^,]+)
```

and then replace:

```
\1
```

with

```
replace
```

Answer (score 1):

In vim:

```
:%s/[^,]\+/replace/g
```

---

```
%            in the whole file
s            substitute
[^,]         match anything except comma
\+           match one or more times
/replace/    replace matched pattern with 'replace'
g            globally (multiple times on the same line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby that would be:

```
original = "string, like , this"
substituted = original.gsub(/[^,]+/, 'replace')
```